# Padding on list items is incorrect in preview

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, list

This is a list without empty lines between items:

---

```
 - Foo
 - Bar
 - Baz
```

- Foo
- Bar
- Baz

---

This is a list with empty lines between items:

```
 - Foo

 - Bar

 - Baz
```

- Foo
- Bar
- Baz

---

Both lists render the same in the editor live preview (click edit on this post to see), but in the submitted/rendered view the list with empty lines has padding between each list item and the list without empty lines has less (although I think it still has too much personally). The rendered view is more correct, so the live preview needs to be updated to show this correctly.

Comment: No repro: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Pi6.png so something on your end. What browser, OS, etc? Using any plugin/extensions/user scripts e.g. SOUP?

Comment: @ShadowWizard that looks like yes-repro to me... the spacing is the same in both instances; it shouldn't be.

Comment: @ShadowWizard here's how it looks in the preview on Super User: http://i.imgur.com/rBMWaQ0.png. That's how it should be.